# ZMQError: Address already in use while using sockets in loops

Tags: python, sockets, zeromq, networkx, pyzmq

I am trying to "simulate message passing between 6 nodes in a distributed environment" using **Zero MQ** in Python, in particular with the classic client/server architecture with **REQ** and **REP**. My idea is, while using a **TCP/IP** connection between these nodes, in the first iteration node-1 must be the server and the clients are the other nodes. In the next one, node-2 will be server and the rest (including node-1) should be clients and so on. At every iteration, server tells that it has established itself and clients send requests to the server to which an acknowledgement is sent back. Once the **ACK** has been received, the clients send their "**MESSAGE**" to the server (which is of course viewed as output) and we move to the next iteration.
The problem now is that I am facing the well known `ZMQError: Address already in use`
I'm not sure if it's due to the socket binding. I have added a `socket.close()` and `context.term()` into both client and server functions, but in vain.
And when I somehow try to run the code the VM goes into deadlock and I'm unable to recover unless I perform a hard reboot. Here is a snippet of my code -

```
@staticmethod
def server(node_id):
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port_s)
    print "Running server node %s on port: %s and value of server = __temp__" % (node_id, port_s)
    message = socket.recv()
    print "Received request : %s from c_node %s and value (temp): __value__" % (message, c_node)
    socket.send("Acknowledged - from %s" % port_s)
    time.sleep(1)
    socket.close()
    context.term() 

@staticmethod    
def client(c_node):

    context = zmq.Context()
#  print "Server node __num__ with port %s" % port_s
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
  #for port in ports:
    socket.connect ("tcp://localhost:%s" % port_c)
#for request in range(20):
    print "c_node %s Sending request to server node __num__" % c_node
    socket.send ("Hello")
    message = socket.recv()
    print "Received ack from server %s and message %s" % (node_id, message)
    time.sleep (1)
    socket.close()
    context.term() 


def node(self, node_id):
    #global node_id
   # global key
#    ser_p = Process(target=self.server, args=(node_id,))


    print 'Memory content of node %d\n' % node_id
    for key in nodes_memory[node_id]:
        print 'Neighbor={%s}, Temp={%s}\n' % (key, nodes_memory[node_id][key])
        #return key
    global c_node
    #key1 = key
#    cli_p = Process(target=self.client, args=(c_node,))


    with open("Book5.csv","r+b") as input:

        has_header = csv.Sniffer().has_header(input.read(1024))
        input.seek(0)  # rewind
        incsv = csv.reader(input)
        if has_header:
            next(incsv)  # skip header

        csv_dict = csv.DictReader(input, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=",")
        node_id = 0
        for row in csv_dict:
            for i in row:
                #print(row[i])
                if type(row[i]) is str:
                    g.add_edge(node_id, int(i), conn_prob=(float(row[i]))) 
            max_wg_ngs = sorted(g[node_id].items(), key=lambda e: e[1]["conn_prob"], reverse=True)[:2]
            #maxim = max_wg_ngs.values.tolist()
            #sarr = [str(a) for a in max_wg_ngs]
            print "\nNeighbours of Node %d are:" % node_id       
            #print(max_wg_ngs)
            ser_p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.server, args=(node_id,))

            ser_p.start()

            for c_node, data in max_wg_ngs:
                for key in nodes_memory[node_id]:    #print ''.join(str(item))[1:-1]
                    #if type(key1) == node_id:
                    cli_p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.client, args=(c_node,))
                    cli_p.start()

                    print('Node {a} with Connection Rate = {w}'.format(a=c_node, w=data['conn_prob']))

                    print('Temperature of Node {a} = {b}'.format(a=c_node, b=nodes_memory[node_id][key]))

            node_id += 1

    pos=nx.spring_layout(g, scale=100.)
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g, pos)
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(g,pos)
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(g,pos)
    #plt.axis('off')
    #plt.show()
```

The "message" is "temperature" (file not shown in the code snippet, but not needed at the moment) and for reference the values of `Book5.csv` are -
`0,1,2,3,4,5
0,0.257905291,0.775104118,0.239086843,0.002313744,0.416936603
0.346100279,0,0.438892758,0.598885794,0.002263231,0.406685237
0.753358102,0.222349243,0,0.407830809,0.001714776,0.507573592
0.185342928,0.571302688,0.51784403,0,0.003231018,0.295197533
0,0,0,0,0,0
0.478164621,0.418192795,0.646810223,0.410746629,0.002414973,0`
`ser_p` and `cli_p` are objects for the server and client functions which are called in the `node` function, i.e `ser_p` is called in the loop `for row in csv_dict` and `cli_p` is called even further in `for c_node, data in max_wg_ngs`. I'm using **Networkx** Python library here as well (Only to find 2 nearest neighbours out of the clients using the connection probability values from `Book5.csv`).
Does anyone know where I might be going wrong? Why is it that it shows address is already in use even though the socket is closed at every iteration?
Thanks a lot in advance :) (Using Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit VM)

Answer (score 1):

### StackOverflow has agreed to use an MCVE-based question asking:

Would you mind to reach that level and complete **the missing part of the MCVE** -- neither **`port_c`**, nor **`port_s`** are lexically correct ( never defined, elsewhere ).

If the code presented here works with a file, always kindly prepare such Minimum-version of the file, that will ensure the MCVE-code work as your expect it to work with the file. Statements like: "*file not shown in the code snippet, but not needed at the moment*" are not compatible with StackOverflow MCVE-rules.

### Next, analyse the logic.

If multiple processes try to **`.bind()`** onto a same port# set via **`port_s`**, they simply will ( and have to ) collide and fall into an exception with `ZMQError: Address already in use`. First reboot the O/S, next pre-scan the already used `IP:port#`-s, next setup the non-colliding server-side `.bind()` ( there could be still a hanging `.context()` with non-terminated `.socket()` instance(s) ( typically from manual prototyping or from unhandled exceptions ), that keep the `IP:port#` without making it free. So the reboot + port scan is a way ahead.

Use any deterministic, principally non-colliding server-2-**`<transport-class://address:port>`** mapping ( `.bind()`-s using wildcards, locking on all IP-adresses, is a bit dangerous habit ) & your code will work smooth.

**Always** use **`<socket>.setsockopt( zmq.LINGER, 0 )`** so as to prevent infinite deadlocks.

Always use `try: {...} except: {...} finally: {...}` formal expressions, so as to avoid any unhandled exceptions to orphan any `.context()` instance outside of your control, perhaps without a graceful .term()-ination and release ( even if new API tells you, that this is not necessary - it is professional to explicitly handle these situations and remain in control, so no exceptions, no excuse ).